# ReactJS preprocessed index.html

Tags: reactjs, facebook

I'm aware that Facebook uses React for developing their front end. I'm a little bit new to ReactJS, and so far I have seen that the server returns the index.html and loads the components on the root div.
Looking at the source code of facebook.com, I realized that the response index.html has some preprocessed data and different scripts. Can anyone tell me how they do for responding with a preprocessed index.html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to render react on the server to enable such functionality. Using a framework like [Nextjs](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/) would help you achieve this.